# can't get flask website from elsewhere

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi 3 and I made a flask webserver, and now I run a website. The problem is that I can only get this website on my pi. I can access that page on my pi by typing 127.0.0.1:5000 in the browser.

If I type without quotation marks `"my_raspbery_pi_ip :5000"` in the browser on my windows laptop or on my android tablet, I get

> page not found my_raspbery_pi_ip is 192.168.0.17

```
pi@piros:~ $ netstat --tcp --listening --programs --numeric
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2322/python     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3350          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3389            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

What can be the problem?

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
from flask import Flask
from time import strftime, sleep, localtime
from flask import render_template
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Comment: Have you try `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` instead of `app.run()`

Comment: I appended the following to the script:

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug = True)

But still "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: What does `netstat` show after your change?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/J7rpKmbu

Answer (score 0):

For another device to be able to reach a web server on your pi, you have to:

1/ make the web server run on '0.0.0.0:5000' so it listens on all ips

2/ configure your pi to accepts incoming requests (on port 5000)  from your local network

3/ make sure your other device is connected to your local network

4/ from your other device's browser (or whatever web client) send a GET request on your_pi_ip:5000

NB : I mention port 5000 here because it seems to be the default used by flask's server, but any free port would do.

NB2 : Of course this will still only make your site accessible from your local network... For a public access you need a publicy accessible server.

Comment: I think I completed everything of your list, but I think I didn't do anythinh in your 2/ line. Could you have a look what the mistake can be? thanks   https://pastebin.com/J7rpKmbu

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be of much help here - I'm a really bad sysadmin, the above list was mostly a 1000 feets high picture. But from your pastebin it looks like your server is still running on 127.0.0.1:5000 (first line of netstats results : "tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2978/python").

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide a code snippet where your web server listens / exposes itself ?

It seems here that your server is listening to 127.0.0.1.
This is the loopback address, meaning it will only receive machine-local requests.

You can use 0.0.0.0 to listen to all addresses.

To do so, you should have something in the flavor of :

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```